# Is it possible to draw charts in ncurses library as below and update in real time?

Tags: c, charts, ncurses, live-update

I found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxbp1.gif) image at [this](https://appliedgo.net/tui/) page and I thought about this in NCURSES library in C. So I have a question could this be done program with live data update on charts like this one above or have you done this before?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to draw charts in ncurses library as below and update in real time?

Yes. You might have to write your own supporting function.

> […] could this be done program with live data update on charts like this one above […]?

Yes. See above.

> […] have you done this before?

No. I never needed to.

Well, probably you will not be satisfied with this answer. May I suggest that you try and write some code to get what you want? And then, if you have a specific question, come back and ask. You'll be welcome!

Anyway, if you like to have such charts, why don't you just use "termui" which is described in the link you gave?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes.

I wrote a terminal utility with ncurses to monitor database activity - it would retrieve and display the most recent transactions for each of our clients, updating ever few seconds.  It didn’t draw any line charts or histograms, but had several windows, would listen for keystrokes, and color coded transactions based on errors.

My code was pretty straightforward as this sort of thing goes, but it was still a bit of work.

Comment: Hi, is your code publicly available? Thanks.

Comment: @hengxin: Unfortunately no, as it contained some proprietary information.  It was also poorly written; I wouldn't want anyone to use it as an example.  It was something I bodged up in my spare time and couldn't devote too many cycles to it.